# Although i use index Mysql query still work slowly

Tags: mysql

Background:

```
 database engine : innodb
    Table a : size:800 000
                column : createDate ,isNomal ,webid …………………………                  
                index ：(createDate ,isNomal ,webid),(webid)
```

Mysql statement:

```
  select count(*) from a h
    where h.createDate BETWEEN '2014-6-1 00:00:00' and '2014-12-1 00:00:00'
    and h.isNomal = 1
    and h.webid = '45334';
```

query explain :

```
id select_type table type possible_keys                    key                key_len  ref    rows Extra
1  SIMPLE        h    ref  FKA3978DBEFB528A46,createDate  FKA3978DBEFB528A46  98      const  3184 using where
```

show profile for query :

```
preparing    2.13-5
executinf    2E-6
Sending data 3.3812
end          5E-6
query end    2E-6
```

mysql-slow-query-log :

```
\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld, Version: 5.1.62-community-log
(MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: (null)
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 150106 12:33:04
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 3.381193  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 3300
use baaa;
SET timestamp=1420518784;
select count(*)
from htmlloadtime h
where h.createDate BETWEEN '2014-6-1 00:00:00' and '2014-12-1 00:00:00'
and h.isNomal = 1
and h.websiteConfigInfo_id = '45334';
```

Myquestion: 
    this query costs 3.3 seconds ,It's too long for me, I want to finish it within 1 seconds, of course,faster is better. how should i do ?  thank you!

---

### After delete the index on  column webid

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `createDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifyDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `isNomal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hhhh` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `webid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `aaa` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate_hour` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate_minute` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate_month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate_second` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKA3978DBE3D0AA64E` (`aaa`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `createDate` (`createDate`,`isNomal`,`webid`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`aaa`) REFERENCES `aaac` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Mysql Statement :

```
 select count(*) from a h
    where h.createDate BETWEEN '2014-6-1 00:00:00' and '2014-12-1 00:00:00'
    and h.isNomal = 1
    and h.webid = '45334';
```

EXPLAIN :

```
id select_type table type possible_keys   key      key_len  ref   rows    Extra
1  SIMPLE        h    range  createDate  createDate  111      null  399486  using where;using index
```

Comment: Are there more rows where createDate is in the range or where webid=45334?

Comment: You're not only working with Humanreadable Dates but also using between, this results in mysql doing the math for you, which is slower than you creating the query manually.
Also is it possible you show us the indexes and number of rows? Also your mysql engine (innodb etc.)

Comment: So what is the actual table schema?

Comment: @Jeredepp: "You're not only working with Humanreadable Dates but also using between, this results in mysql doing the math for you, which is slower than you creating the query manually." --- this is **WRONG**

Comment: @zerkms enlighten me, and tell me why there are no ticks lost in the process of rewriting my query

Comment: @Jeredepp: because they are literals for the built in timestamp type http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given query the index must be

```
(webid, isNomal, createDate)
```

in this particular order.

The main difference is that the column that is used for range type comparison must be the last one. Since after the last comparison is applied no further columns may be used.

For your current query it is a single column index over the `h.webid` is used, which causes mysql to first - lookup the corresponding rows (~3300 of them) in the index, then perform additional predicates check over the real data rows.

Comment: OK, I will delete the index on column webid and try it again! by the way,thanks for answer my question.

Comment: unfortunately,it doesn't work ! I deleted the index on column webid and then it costs 10 seconds .     query explain :    possible_keys     rows  createDate  399486

Comment: @FLY: provide the current `SHOW CREATE TABLE` + complete `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @FLY I don't see the index I suggested to create. Please read the 3 first lines in my answer carefully.

Comment: KEY `createDate` (`createDate`,`isNomal`,`webid`) USING BTREE   ! Isn't it?  Ijust use these columns in my where clause .

Comment: @FLY: "**in this particular order.**" The order matters. So, no, you haven't created the index I suggested

Comment: I'm sorry ! I don't understand. in my index ,the order is "createDate,isNomal,webid " , and in my where clause It's "createDate between , isNomal = ,webid = " ,why the differences ?

Comment: @FLY: oh my god. The index must be created with columns `(webid, isNomal, createDate)` **IN THIS PARTICULAR ORDER**. Index is an **ORDERED STRUCTURE**. It does not matter how you query it in your `WHERE` clause, but in the `CREATE TABLE` it must go in the **EXACT ORDER** I suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much,It works. I create the index like you said,and now It just cost about 0.004 seconds. At last, would you mind tell me where did you see the rule " column that is used for range type comparison must be the last one" ? official documentation or some book ?  And could you please suggest some book  about mysql to me?   please forgive my poor english. the book, i mean ,it contains some unkonw point just like the knowledge you mentioned before.   thanks for your patience!

Comment: @FLY it's explained at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html "8.2.1.3.2 The Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes". Reading mysql documentation would be enough at first. "Chapter 8 Optimization" chapter is detailed enough, but be prepared that it's not an easy reading.